# Problem with trig inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have this derivative and I want to check where it is positive for $x>1$ (so it is increasing)

$-\frac{x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+2}{x^2}$

The answer states that $x\sin(x)$ must be greater than $-3$. and then it says for some values like $2k\pi+\pi/3$ it is greater than $-3$.

but I have no idea where that $-3$ comes from. 
I thought It should be something like this $x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+2<0 => x\sin(x)+\cos(x) <-2$ but from here I don't have any idea how I can solve this.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n1jpcpldek

Comment: For $x=\pi$, it is equal to $-1/\pi^2$.

Comment: Yes, it's impossible. What is an original problem?

Comment: @Bernard I don't get it. How is that useful?

Comment: The original problem is Integral convergence test. It must be always decreasing so we can apply the test, so we should take the derivative of the function and see if it is always decreasing.

Comment: @roshanaie It is a nice way but I am afraid of its limitations. Can I apply it to every function?

Comment: Your problem might be more deeper than you expect

Comment: @GuyFsone I was never good at math, however I try hard to get better. So what you think is my problem?

Comment: I have sketch answer for you

Answer (score 0):

First it is enough to study the sign of $f(x) =x\sin x + \cos x +2$ since $-\frac{1}{x^2}<0$ for all $x>1$
but

$$ f'(x)= x\cos x =  \Longleftrightarrow x= \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi ~~~k\in \mathbb N\cup \{0\}$$

on $(1,\infty),$ we have $$f'(x)\ge 0   \Longleftrightarrow x\in [1,\frac{\pi}{2}]\cup\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}+(2k-1)\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right]\implies f \qquad\text{increase on each interval}$$
and 
$$f'(x)\le 0   \Longleftrightarrow x\in \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}+(2k+1)\pi\right]\implies f \qquad\text{decay on each interval}$$

also $$f ( \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi )=(-1)^k( \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)$$
ie 
$$f ( \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi )= \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi>0\quad \text{and}\quad f ( \frac{\pi}{2}+(2k+1)\pi )=- ( \frac{\pi}{2}+(2k+1)\pi)<0. $$
Hence for each $k\in \mathbb N\cup \{0\}$ there is $x_k\in \left[\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}+(k+1)\pi\right]$ such that $f(x_k)= 0$

Therefore

$$f(x)\ge 0\Longleftrightarrow  x\in [x_{2k},x_{2k+1}]~~k\ge 1\qquad \text{or}\qquad x\in [1,\frac{\pi}{2}]$$
and $$f(x)\le 0\Longleftrightarrow  x\in [x_{2k-1},x_{2k}]~~ k\ge 1$$
adding the factor $-x^{-2}$ the result follows.

Comment: It is embarrassing, that after 1 year studying math in Khan Academy I am not able to understand your answer. First of all, I don't get it, why you wrote x*cos(x) and then you concluded pi/2 + k*pi.

Comment: Explain your problem and what you dont understand. Or you might another second years in your academy